# What was the two guys' relationship in the suits?

Tags: character, snowpiercer

In Snowpiercer there were two guys in suits (the one in the blue suit, and the one in the grey suit, one was young and one was old). In the beginning, the one in the blue suit was lying on the guy with the grey suit's shoulder. I was just wondering if they were in a relationship?

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that they were family members but in no way do I have any reason to think this is the actual answer other than my vague impression.

Comment: @Andrew - They were indeed [brothers](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52171/7812), not lovers.

Answer (score 3):

[This interview](http://clothesonfilm.com/snowpiercer-qa-with-costume-designer-catherine-george/35353/) with the film's Costume Designer (Catherine George) indicates that two characters; Franco the Elder and Franco the Younger were in fact brothers.

> **CoF:** *Was it your intention to make Franco the Elder and Franco the Younger (Vlad Ivanov and Adnan Haskovic?) look like the Guido
>   brothers? I assume in his former life Franco the Elder was definitely
>   an enforcer.*
>
> **CG:** *Yes I imagine that he was some kind of enforcer or hit man. He certainly takes a long time to die. I had actually started looking
>   at the images of assassins and brothers and looked at the Kray twins
>   with their history of violence and their style. **Director Bong really
>   liked the idea of that violence and style coupled with love for his
>   brother.***

and from the [movie script](http://www.scriptdrive.net/attachment.php?aid=2029) (*registration required*)

> Suddenly, a spear flies in from out of nowhere and pierces Arabic
>   Man’s chest. As he falls, another heavy spear flies through the air
>   towards Curtis. At the last moment, Curtis deflects the spear with his
>   axe blade.
>
> Everyone turns and looks in the direction from which the spears came:
>   **the Franco Brothers.**